# How can I show the map layer ui?

Tags: genshin-impact

With the release of version 4.0 layered maps are now in the game, allowing you to swap between surface level and lower levels.

When you select something 'underground' the layers map ui is shown.

[image: Surface and underground map selection ui]

Can I show this UI without needing to select something 'underground'? I am looking for a Hydroculus, but I can't check the lower level maps easily, as I have not uncovered them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I missed that it is context sensitive. As you pan the map around, the ui will pop in and also adjust automatically to the number of layers present on your cursor.

I recorded the behaviour. Keep an eye on the right hand side.